# If else statement in ajax call not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

For some reason the if else statement I have to weed out mistyped api searches is not doing its job. The ajax request is coming back with the no-results message div ALONG WITH the correct search result.

When there is actually no result it seems to filter okay and display the message.

Here's the ajax request along with the success logic:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "apis/api",
  type: "get",
  dataType: "json",

  success: function(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") {
      $("#results").html(data);
    } else { 
      $("#results").html("<div class='no-results'>No matches.</div>");
    }
  }
});
```

I also tried this success block, which doesn't actually make it to the else condition:

```
 success: function(data) {
    if ($(document).ajaxSuccess()){
      $("#results").html(data);
    } else {
      $("#results").html("<div class='no-results'>No matches.</div>");
    }
  }
```

I tried reversing the if else statements with a != but no luck.

Not sure why this wouldn't work. Please help, thank you!

Comment: `if ($(document).ajaxSuccess()){` doesn't do what you think it does.  `$(document).ajaxSuccess()` is used to attach a *callback* to the successful AJAX calls.  You would do `$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){})`.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show you?

Comment: @RocketHazmat It returns Object {response: Object}

Comment: That's why `if (data.status == "success") {` isn't working.  It doesn't have a `status` property.  It has `data.response`.  So you can try to check `if(data.response){} else{}`.  P.S. `$("#results").html(data);` don't be useful since `data` is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you are making a call to an external API, I would assume that the object being returned does not have a "status" attribute at the root level, hence the `data.status` will always return `nil`. If that is the case your the first condition `if (data.status == "success")` will always evaluate to false, and the second part of the conditional will evaluate.
Use a `console.log` or `debugger` to get a better idea of what the object you've returned contains, and then rethink the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible that both your `if` and `else` branches would execute **in the same call**, which means that you are making multiple requests to the server and getting multiple results.

This is most likely because you are sending a request every time the user-entered text changes.  You need to debounce requests using a technique similar to that described in [Debouncing JavaScript Methods](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/).  If the user types some text while you have a server request outstanding, you'll also need to cancel any pending requests before sending the new one.

Handling all of this correctly can be tricky, so I'd recommend using one of the many pre-built jQuery plugins for this task:

- https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ (I've used this one very successfully)
- http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
- https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete
- https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q=jquery+autocomplete

Comment: +1 Since OP is probably running the ajax attached to the `keyup` event.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your HTML looks like, but seems that you may need to change `get` to `post`. Since you are also using `json`, seems that you need to specify the correct key in your json data array.

Similar to your `data.status`, your HTML should be something like `data.html`.

```
$json = array('status' => 'success', 'html' => '<div>Some HTML</div>');
echo json_encode($json);
```

Supposing that you are using PHP.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "apis/api",
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",

  success: function(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") {
      $("#results").html(data.html);
    } else { 
      $("#results").html("<div class='no-results'>No matches.</div>");
    }
  }
});
```